# When would it make sense to have several beat sheets for several stories happening in parallel?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, story

When would it make sense to have several beat sheets for several stories happening in parallel? I was thinking of writing a story where there are several stories happening at the same time, and three main characters would have his own beat sheets, would that make any sense, or is it always better to have one beat sheet for the whole book?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you find useful.

Beat sheets are not requirements, but analyzed structures that some writers find useful.  If you find it useful to have several, go ahead.

The only problem might lie in whether the story lines are integrated enough to form a unified story, and that lies in having several stories, not using beat sheets for them.

Answer (score 1):

For me, beat sheets are the way I remember stuff. Otherwise, I leave stuff out. I will also stick in bits of conversation or description that occurs to me while I'm fixing the beats.

When you have things happening in parallel they can also be a way to map out the timing. It can be a bit tedious getting the timing correct even with a map of the beats. You have to estimate how long each thing takes. Usually the way to do that is to cheat a little. For example, having conversations take more or less time than realistically required. Or have your character take a little more or less time walking, or some such thing.

But if party A is going round *this* side, and party B is going round *that* side, and they are supposed to meet up just *here* then beat sheets are one way to have that happen without leaving annoying gaps. You don't want party B to get there hours early and stand around looking bored (and boring your readers) while they wait for party A.